# Examine uniform convergence of function series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(1+(x-n)^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Examine uniform convergence of function series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(1+(x-n)^2)}$

**My try:**

Let $$g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(1+(x-n)^2)}$$ 
 Note that for $$f_n=\frac{\arctan (x-n)}{n}$$ we have: $$f'_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(1+(x-n)^2)}=g_n(x)$$So if $\sum g_n$ is pointwise convergence then $\sum f'_n$ is uniform convergence. 
However we know that for enought big $n$: $f'_n \le \frac{-1}{n}$ so number series $\sum f'_n$ is divergent so function series $\sum f'_n$ is not pointwise convergent so also is not uniform convergent.
 That's why $\sum g_n$ is not pointwise convergent and also uniform.
However I have doubt if this fact is "$\Leftrightarrow$" or implication and it does not work in the side in which I used it.
Can you check it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your argument with $f_n'$. $f_n'$ is never negative, so the inequality $f_n'<-1/n$ can't be right. Perhaps you meant $f_n$? But you are going in the right direction - just because the $f_n$ series diverges doesn't mean the $g_n$ series does. In fact, $\sum g_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Here's a proof, but it's quite finicky in places.

Let $G_n=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k$ and $G=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}G_n$ (right now we don't even know if it exists). Always keep in mind that all the terms we are dealing with are positive. The strategy is the following: suppose we manage to show that

- $G_n$ converges uniformly on every bounded interval,
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}G(x)=0$.

Say we've done this. Since $g_n(-x)\leq g_n(x)$, it's also true that $G(-x)\leq G(x)$ and so $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}G(x)=0$ implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}G(x)=0$. Now for uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ we must show that $$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n>N\,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\,\left\vert G(x)-G_n(x)\right\vert <\epsilon$$
Basically, we only need to go up to $N$ and we'll be pretty close to $G$ everywhere.
Now pick an $\epsilon$. Due to $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}G(x)=0$ we can choose a bounded interval $I$ so big that $G < \epsilon$ everywhere outside $I$. Since $0<G_n(x)<G(x)$, automatically we have $\left\vert G(x)-G_n(x)\right\vert <\epsilon$ on $\mathbb{R}-I$. But since $I$ is bounded, we can pick an $N$ so big that for all $n>N: \left\vert G(x)-G_n(x)\right\vert <\epsilon$ holds inside $I$ as well, thus proving convergence is uniform on $(\mathbb{R}-I)\cup\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$.

Now for the two statements.

---

- $G_n$ converges uniformly on every bounded interval

Let $(a,b)$ be our interval. We can pick $K$ large enough that for $k>K$ we have $k-x > k/2$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ and so for such $k$:
$$
g_k(x) = \frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}<\frac{1}{k(1+(k/2)^2)}<\frac{4}{k^3}
$$
The series $\sum k^{-3}$ is well-know to be convergent and so $\sum g_k(x)$ is convergent on $(a,b)$. Furthermore, we estimate the remainder:
$$
\vert G(x)-G_n(x)\vert = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty g_k(x)<\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{4}{k^3}
$$
As this bound on the remainder is independent of $x$, we have uniform convergence on $(a,b)$ (notice, however, that this does not suffice for uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$, as $K$ depends on the choice of interval).

---

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}G(x)=0$

This is somewhat convoluted, but I didn't find a simpler way. We would like to take 
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}
$$
and somehow bound it from above by something that vanishes at infinity. So, pick a big $x$ and split $G(x)$ into three parts:
$$
G(x) = S_1(x)+S_2(x)+S_3(x)\\
S_1(x)=\sum_{1\leq k<x-x^{2/3}} \frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}\\
S_2(x)=\sum_{x-x^{2/3}\leq k\leq x+x^{2/3}}\frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}\\
S_3(x)=\sum_{x+x^{2/3}<k}\frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}
$$
Let's get to bounding!

- $S_1$

It is true that $x-k > x^{2/3}$, so we have:
$$
S_1(x)=\sum_{1\leq k<x-x^{2/3}} \frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}<\sum_{1\leq k<x-x^{2/3}}\frac{1}{1+(x^{2/3})^2}<\frac{x}{1+x^{4/3}}<x^{-1/3}
$$

- $S_2$
  $$
  S_2(x)=\sum_{x-x^{2/3}\leq k\leq x+x^{2/3}}\frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}<\sum_{x-x^{2/3}\leq k\leq x+x^{2/3}}\frac{1}{x-x^{2/3}}\leq\frac{2x^{2/3}+2}{x-x^{2/3}}
  $$
- $S_3$
  $$
  S_3(x)=\sum_{x+x^{2/3}<k}\frac{1}{k(1+(k-x)^2)}<\sum_{x+x^{2/3}<k}\frac{1}{(k-x)^3}<
  \sum_{x^{2/3}-1\leq k}\frac{1}{k^3}
  $$

$S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ all go to $0$ at infinity ($S_3$ because it is the remainder of $\sum k^{-3}$), thus finally establishing $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}G(x)=0$.

---

Now that uniform convergence has been established, we can also integrate $G$ termwise:
$$
\int_0^x G(t)\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{arctan}(x-k)+\mathrm{arctan(k)}}{k}
$$
Now this isn't precisely the $f_k$ series you had, it has an extra arctangent in the numerator. Without it, the series would diverge for all $x$, as you correctly pointed out. I believe the problem was that you just took an indefinite integral of the terms, but (at least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability) makes it seem that) you can only take definite integrals and you simply can't get the $f_n$ series you described out of the definite integral.